# DOMPDF repeat element in dynamic page

Tags: dompdf

I am generating a report using dompdf.  And tried repeating an element in a page where it could take up to 4 pages depending on the data.  But it only created on the first page

Currently i have this html markup.

```html
<html>
  <head>
<style>
  @page { 
 margin: .5in;  
  }
  .footer{
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 bottom:60px; 
  }
  .page-3{
 position:relative;
  }
  .repeat{
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
                top:10px;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>  
 
<div class="page page-1">
  <div class="content">
 <div class="content-header">...</div>
 <div class="content-text">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page page-2">
  <div class="content">
 <div class="content-header">...</div>
 <div class="content-text">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page page-3">
  <div class="content">
 <div class="content-header repeat">
   This must repeat in all pages generated
 </div>
 <div class="content-text">
   atleast 2~4 pages
 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page page-4">
  <div class="content">
 <div class="content-header">...</div>
 <div class="content-text">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Let's say `.page-3` generated 3 pages.  But the `.repeat` is only seen on the first page inside `.page-3`

I tried using a background image for `.page-3` but it still the same and is shown only on the first generated page.

I using the `0.8.2` version of dompdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having a same problem as i have.  I end up using a `page_script`.

Since i know the first 2 pages are static and the last page is static, I accessed the `$PAGE_NUM` and place a condition like this

`

```
    $pdf->page_script('
            if( $PAGE_NUM != 1 ){ // 1st page has no header
                $text = "";
                if( $PAGE_NUM == 2 ){
                    $text = "This is 2nd page";
                }else if( $PAGE_NUM > 2 && $PAGE_NUM < $PAGE_COUNT ){
                    $text = "This is the page 3 until before the last page";
                }else if( $PAGE_NUM == $PAGE_COUNT ){
                    $text = "This is last page";
                }

                // setup postioning, color, size etc for design     

                // use $text as header text                 
                $pdf->text( $posX, $posY, $text, $font, $size, $color);
            }

    ');
```

`

And removed all `<div class="content-header">...</div>` in the HTML markup